# Why is the onauxclick event triggered in a different way in google chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, event-handling

So i developed a web app and i used `onauxclick` on a functionality. When i went to test it on firefox browser it all went perfectly. I tested it with google chrome browser and the `onauxclick` event handler wasn't working when pressing down the mouse wheel. After few more testing i was able to make it work by selecting the text and pressing the right mouse button (without leaving the selected text). So i was wondering, how does it work differently on google chrome browser and windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the different browser vendors try to stay as close as possible to the W3C standards when implement HTML and JavaScript features, they do tend to sometimes introduce minor differences between implementations or even not implement some stuff at all.

The feature you are trying to use is at the moment experimental and not supported on Safari and Safari iOS. Expect it to change a bit until it is finalised and released.

More details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onauxclick

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know why in linux all works perfectly and the issue is with windows only? both google chrome versions are the last one (86).

Comment: I wouldn't be able to say. It might just be that a small bug seeped through the Linux or Windows version and it is not the intended behavior. What you can do is double check that the behavior you see is consistent and if indeed it is and it is really important for you that it works in a certain way you can always check on which OS is your code running and build a workaround accordingly.

Is my answer was satisfactory, please don't hesitate to mark it, thanks!